# How to binding a method call on one object to a method call on another object using C++17 stdlib?

Tags: c++

It is necessary to install objects and methods to handle events in another object, how can this be implemented using C++17 and stdlib?

```
class A {
public:
    void eventA(int value) {}
};

class B {
public:
    void handlerA(int value) {}
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    connect(&a, &A::eventA, &b, &B::handlerA);

    // The handlerA method of object b must be called
    a.eventA(42);

    return 0;
}
```

Update 1: I found a way to bind event handlers using std::bind, but there is a need to specify the number of arguments in the binding function, is it possible to make it so that you do not need to specify the number of arguments?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class A {
public:
    std::function<void(int)> event1{[](int){}};
    std::function<void(int,int)> event2{[](int,int){}};
};

class B {
public:
    void handler1(int value) {
        std::cout << "B: " << value << std::endl;
    }
};

class C {
public:
    void handler2(int value1, int value2) {
        std::cout << "C: " << value1 << " " << value2 << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class R, class E, class H, class... Types>
void connect(E& event, R& receiver, H handler, Types... args) {
    event = std::bind(handler, &receiver, args...);
}

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    // You need to specify the number of arguments, is it possible to 
    // make the function call like connect(a.event1, b, &B::handler1)?
    connect(a.event1, b, &B::handler1, std::placeholders::_1);
    connect(a.event2, c, &C::handler2, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);

    // The handler1 method of object b must be called
    a.event1(42);
    // The handler2 method of object c must be called
    a.event2(42, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Update 2: I found a way to not specify arguments using std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, etc., to do this you need to use a lambda with automatic inference of argument types

```
template<class R, class E, class H>
void connect(E& event, R& receiver, H handler) {
    event = [&receiver, handler](auto... args) { (receiver.*handler)(args...); };
}
```

Comment: It is called **binding** of so-called _properties_; language agnostic. You could search some examples. Not necessarily apply it as sole solution everywhere though.

Comment: To meaningfully design this, you need to decide several things first: 1. Can multiple objects emit events to the same handler? (answering "no" tends to result in better design, in my experience) 2. Can multiple handlers listen to the same emitter? (usually "yes") 3. Can the handler die before the emitter? If yes, the emitter needs to be aware of that and not try to poke a dead object.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat 1. yes, 2. yes, 3. yes. That is, it is impossible to implement the described behavior only using the language and the stdlib library; it is necessary to design a complex system, like the one implemented in Qt?

Comment: Ultimately everything is implemented using the language itself. Perhaps not as complex as Qt's, but this does require manual work. The most basic approach would be to inherit subscribers from an abstract class with pure virtual methods for the handlers, have a `std::vector<std::weak_ptr<YourBase>>` somewhere to call the handlers, and store a `shared_ptr` to the list in the emitters. Then, during emitting, kick dead pointers from the list.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Perhaps std::bind would be suitable for this? However, it is not yet clear how to store its result in object A. Because in the general case, objects do not know about each other.

Comment: `std::bind` is useless. It's strictly worse than a lambda, a lambda can do anything it does, and it has a fatal flaw: it silently discards any excessive arguments you give it. There are `std::bind_front` and `std::bind_back`, which are fine, and provide some convenience over a lambda.

Comment: *"how to store its result in object A"* With the approach I suggested, you'd just store a pointer to base.

Answer (score 2):

C++ has two useful tools for this

- std::function<retval_t (args_t...)> to hold functions
- lambda expressions

With this you can build your event handling like this and you will not have to write any infrastructure of your own.
Live demo here : https://onlinegdb.com/ZHL7sL_kB

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class class_with_event_t
{
public:
    class_with_event_t() :
        // default is a callback that does nothing
        // the [](int){} is a lambda expression (representing a function accepting an int returning void)
        m_count{0},
        m_on_count{[](int){}} 
    {
    }

    // set a function to call when count is updated
    void set_on_count_handler(std::function<void(int)> handler)
    {
        m_on_count = handler;
    }

    void count()
    {
        ++m_count;
        m_on_count(m_count);
    }



private:
    int m_count;
    std::function<void (int)> m_on_count;
};


int main()
{
    class_with_event_t object;

    // only default handler that does nothing is called
    object.count();

    object.set_on_count_handler([](int count) 
    {
        std::cout << "count = " << count << "\n";
    });

    object.count();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`eventA` gets to decide what it does. Outside code doesn't get to make that decision. If `eventA` doesn't call `handlerA` (and doesn't provide a mechanism to call a parameter handler), then there's no way to demand that it do so in the abstract.

The usual way to change an instance method's behavior is to wrap it in the *newtype pattern*. That is, rather than calling `A.eventA`, we'll define a new class that contains an `A` and has an `eventA` favorable to our situation.

```
class AWrapper {
private:
    A& implementation;
    B& delegate;
public:
    AWrapper(A& implementation, B& delegate) :
        implementation(implementation), delegate(delegate) {}

    void eventA(int value) {
        implementation.eventA();
        delegate.handlerA();
    }

};
```

Now as long as we call `eventA` through our wrapper object, we get the desired behavior. But this isn't magic; it won't change the actual `A` object's behavior at its core. C++ does not provide a standard mechanism to do so.

Comment: Do not use reference members unless you know what it entails and place a giant disclaimer somewhere.